# Make a field visible when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make visible some hidden forms on-click of the submit button..
that is to say if you click the submit button other fields will become visible making the submit button invisible

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: -1 for no research effort and unclear.

Comment: If you are new,has just started to learn a particular topic then its better that you mention that you are a beginner.

Comment: Using Java or JavaScript? How are you using PHP with android? What have you tried? We need more info to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

**HTML**

```html
<form id="formId" onsubmit="formSubmit('formId');">
     <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS with JQuery**

```js
function formSubmit(formId){  
if (formId != ''){
    $('#btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);
    document.getElementById(formId).submit();
} }
```

Comment: Maybe you can add some explanation for the answer. +1 for your code.

Comment: Javascript isn't even needed for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to do this.

Use `.show()` method to show some elements. Check http://api.jquery.com/show/

Use `.hide()` method to hide some elements. Check http://api.jquery.com/hide/